React app cant connect to Spring Boot websocket
Im trying to setup a basic websocket in using Spring Boot (v3.4.0 with Java 21).
this is what my WebSocketConfig.java looks like
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("Registering WebSocket endpoint: /ws");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws").withSockJS();
    }
}

with this controller
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/sample")
@CrossOrigin
public class SampleController {
    
    @Autowired
    private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/test")
    public String testGet() {
        return "get working";
    }
    
    
    @GetMapping(path = "/websocket/sample")
    public void testWebsocket() {
        messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/data-update", "Data updated!");
    }
    
}

then for the frontend i just have this to check if its connecting
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Client } from "@stomp/stompjs";
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";

const WebSocketTest = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    // WebSocket connection
    const socket = new SockJS("http://localhost:8080/ws");
    const stompClient = new Client({
      webSocketFactory: () => socket,
      debug: (str) => console.log(str),
      onConnect: () => {
        console.log("Connected to WebSocket");

        stompClient.subscribe("/topic/data-update", () => {
           console.log("Triggered");
        });
      },
      onStompError: () => {
        console.log("error");
      },
    });

    stompClient.activate();

    return () => {
      stompClient.deactivate();
    };
  }, []);

  return <h1>Listening for WebSocket updates...</h1>;
};

export default WebSocketTest;

It wont connect and on the browser console i only get this
enter image description here
but i get these logs in spring
enter image description here

It might be because the CORS configuration is missing in the WebSocketConfig. Try adding the following and attempt again:
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        System.out.println("Registering WebSocket endpoint: /ws");
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*") // <- this part is added.
                .withSockJS();
    }
}

The wildcard ("*") inside .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*") should only be used for debugging in a development environment. In a production environment, you should specify the actual URLs.
